# Flask session does't work - react & flask app

Tags: python, reactjs

I'm working on an app with flask backend and react front,
I want to save the username in a session and display it in the front post-login.

here is the current process:

1. configurations at the head of app.py (flask-server main file)

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] = "key"
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "pass"
app.config["JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES"] = timedelta(hours=1)
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = 'filesystem'
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
# app.config.from_object(__name__)

CORS(app)
Session(app)
jwt = JWTManager(app)
```

2. Login button with handler:

```
const data = {
      username: loginForm.username,
      password: loginForm.password
    }
fetch("http://localhost:5000/token", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then((response) => {...
```

3. the route for "/token" - if the credentials are ok it renders my user homepage, and it works fine.

```
@app.route('/token', methods=["POST"])
def create_token():
    username = json.loads(request.data)["username"]
    password = json.loads(request.data)["password"]
    sql_string = f"""select username, password from admins where username='{username}'"""
    result = sql_call(sql_string) //this is a helper functino in db_connector file
    if(result):
       session["username"] = username
       access_token = create_access_token(identity=username) //another helper function
       response = app.response_class(response=json.dumps({"access_token": access_token}),
                                  status=200,
                                  mimetype='application/json')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response
```

4. on the app main page i have a span of "Hello " that tries to fetch the username from the session, sending request to route "/username":

```
@app.route("/username")
def getUsername():
    username = session["username"]
    response = jsonify({"username": "admin"})
    return response
```

But it finds no key "username" in the session, and also the SID in 4 and SID in 3 are different.
how can I retrieve this data back?

my flask runs on port 5000 and react on port 3000,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In step 4 use this to get username

```
session.get("username")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't manage to fix it,
session.get("username" also didn't work)

I noticed that the server is working fine when sending requests from postman, so the problem might be in React.

I used the get_jtw()
over the session and it works well :)